# displaytag export xml is not displaying tags

Tags: xml, struts, displaytag

I am using display tag in my struts application. excel,csv export are fine. Xml export is not displaying the start tags or element tags but simply display the values like below.

158 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60  240.0 263 317 249 278 245 130 159 156

i want output like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <table>
    <row>
    <column>158</column>
    <column>60</column>
    <column>60</column>
    <column>60</column>
    <column>60</column>
    <column>60</column>
    <column>60</column>
    <column>60</column>
    <column>60</column>
    </row>
    <row>
    <column>240.0</column>
    <column>263</column>
    <column>317</column>
    <column>249</column>
    <column>278</column>
    <column>245</column>
    <column>130</column>
    <column>159</column>
    <column>156</column>
    </row>
    </table>
```

can someone help?

Comment: My guess is you're not actually exporting XML or you're viewing it in something that hides or suppresses the tags. Show us your display tag table code.

Comment: @BeauGrantham <display:table id="timetable" name='${ctvactionform.ctvlist}' 
  requestURI="/oee/ctvaction.do" export="true" 
  decorator="dyndecorator" >
  
  <display:setProperty name="export.banner" value='<div class="exportlinks_ctv">Export options: {0}</div>'></display:setProperty>
  
  <c:if test="${ctvactionform.displaytype != 'Cykeltid/dag'}">
  <display:column title="Tid" property="timestamp" sortable="true" style="white-space: nowrap;"/>
  </c:if>

Comment: <c:if test="${ctvactionform.displaytype == 'Cykeltid/dag'}">
  <display:column title="Tid" media="html" sortable="true" style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <html:link 
  href="/oee/ctvaction.do?Task=visamedtid&amp;tidfr=${timetable.timestamp}">${timetable.timestamp}</html:link>
  </display:column>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${ctvactionform.displaytype == 'Alla cykler'}">
  <display:column title="${ctvactionform.machine}" property="fstation" sortable="true" style="nowrap;" format="{0,number,0.0}" />
  </c:if>

Comment: <c:if test="${ctvactionform.antrob > 0}">
  <display:column title="${ctvactionform.rob1}" property="rob1" />
   <c:if test="${ctvactionform.shostatus == '1'}">
   <display:column title="D" property="rob1pr" class="" />
   </c:if>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${ctvactionform.antrob > 1}">
  <display:column title="${ctvactionform.rob2}" property="rob2" />
   <c:if test="${ctvactionform.shostatus == '1'}">
   <display:column title="D" property="rob2pr" class="" />
   </c:if>
  </c:if>

Comment: <display:footer>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="6"></td>
        </tr>
      </display:footer>
  </display:table>

Comment: The issue is that same code works and shows the tags in IE9 , its not showing the tags in IE11.